# Do allies provide cover to enemies vs. attacks with reach weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-wrath-of-the-righteous

In the *Pathfinder* 1e tabletop game, attacking with a reach weapon is normally penalized if there's an ally between you and the target (the enemy is considered to have "soft cover"). The tabletop game also has a feat called [Phalanx Formation](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/phalanx-formation-combat/) that negates this penalty.

I notice that the Phalanx Formation feat isn't in *WotR*. Is the soft cover penalty for reach weapons in *WotR* at all, or is the feat unnecessary because the penalty just doesn't exist?